# Google maps inside an hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Basically we have a button and on a click an image is faded out showing the google map underneath (Gmap it is shown full screen as it is the image). But when I hit the button and the image fades out, the map isn't displayed. Doesn't appear at all.

This is my html structure

```
    <div id="map" class="wrapMap hidden-xs hidden-sm">
       <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="img_img row hidden-xs hidden-sm">
       <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="../img/home_img.jpg" alt="" />
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-home-img">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 hp-img-map">
            <p class="view-map"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> View map</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Css (**NOTE** If I don't use `!important` the div doesn't hide, I believe it is due to gmaps loading)

```
.wrapMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none !important;
}
```

Jquery

```
    $(".row-home-img").on("click", function(){
       $(".img_img").fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
          $(".wrapMap").show();             
       });
    });
```

I read about adding this to the jQuery once the div is visible but it isn't working for me

```
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fEA9/

Comment: `$(".wrapMap").show();`  (you've ommitted the parentheses)

Comment: Fixed. that was a typo. Issue remains.

Comment: Create a fiddle of you current implementation

Comment: When the image fades out, gmap show be displayed http://jsfiddle.net/5fEA9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the img inside the container div of the map:

```
    <div id="map" class="wrapMap hidden-xs hidden-sm">
       <div class="img_img row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../img/home_img.jpg" alt="Rent a boat to sail" />
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
```

Then on Jquery

```
$(".row-home-img").on("click", function(){
    $(".img_img").fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
        $(this).css("display","none");
        initialize();
        google.maps.event.addListener(map,"idle", function(){ 
            $("#map-canvas").css({ opacity: 1, zoom: 1});
        });             
    });
});
```

And removed the `display: none !important` from the css

Answer (score 0):

`$.show()` will set the display to `block`, what will not override the !important-rule defined the global style.

Some options:

set the style via cssText:

```
  $(".row-home-img").on("click", function(){
       $(".img_img").fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
          $(".wrapMap")[0].style.cssText='display:block !important';           
       });
    });
```

I would prefer to use a different class that only contains:

```
display: none !important;
```

Add this class to .wrapMap and instead of using show() remove this class

Comment: solved it by myself. Check my answer. Thanks a lot tho